# How to prove that $f$ is an injection when for each non-empty subset $A$ of $\operatorname{Dom}(f)$, $A=f^{-1} [f(A)]?$

Tags: functional-analysis

I was given to prove that $f$ is an injection iff for each non-empty subset $A$ of $\operatorname{Dom}(f)$, $A=f^{-1} [f(A)].$
I was able to prove that $A=f^{-1} [f(A)]$ when $f$ is an injection. I want to solve the converse.

I supposed that $A=f^{-1} [f(A)]$ and that $x$ is not equal to a where $x$,$a$ are elements of $A$.then $f(x)\in f(A)$ and $f(a)\in f(A).$ Is my approach to this is correct$?$ if so how can I proceed with this?

Comment: What have you tried ? This is your second question in under 2 hours. Please show your efforts here so that someone can guide you.  Use definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = f^{-1}(f(A))$ for each non empty subset $A$ of $\operatorname{dom}(f)$. For $a \in A$ you have $a \in f^{-1}(f(A))$ or equivalently $f(a) \in f(A)$.

Now let $x,y\in \operatorname{dom}(f)$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. Of course you have $f(x) \in f(\{x\})$ but also $f(y) \in f(\{x\})$ because of the equality. By the statement above $y \in \{x\}$ i.e. $x=y$ follows, hence $f$ is injective.